# How to read from SQL database table and reorder the rows?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.
I have Addresses Table in MSSQL server and I search for all house numbers based on the postcode and then add them in a `flowLayoutPanel` as shown in screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I use this code to view all house numbers related to the postcode.

```
DataTable Data_Table          = new DataTable();
SqlConnection MyConnection    = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand MySQLCommand       = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
string postCode = "L8 8HN";

Data_Table.Rows.Clear();
Data_Table.Columns.Clear();
MyConnection.ConnectionString = " Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=PC ;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=1024; Pooling=true";
MyConnection.Open();
MySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PC where Postcode = '" + postCode + "'";
MySQLCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = MySQLCommand;

SQLDataAdapter.Fill(Data_Table);
MySQLCommand.Parameters.Clear();
SQLDataAdapter.Dispose();
MyConnection.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Button btn    = new Button();
    btn.Text      = Data_Table.Rows[i]["House_Number"].ToString();
    btn.Width     = 188;
    btn.Height    = 75;
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
    btn.Font      = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);
    btn.BackColor = Color.FromName("White");                            
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot the house numbers are not in orders. I want to view/add the numbers starting from small number to big. For example (2, 76, 78, 80...).

if I use this clause: `order by House_Number` it views like this (100, 102, 104, 106, 108,.... then 2, 76, 78 ....)

Anyone knows how to do it? maybe there is a query which can read and reorder them or may be there are other ways.

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL?  But be aware of the differences between sorting *numbers* and sorting *text*.  Your value appears to be text.  If you want to sort by numbers then you should probably store the data as numbers.  (Otherwise you're going to be parsing strings into numbers, which isn't fun.)

Comment: List<DataRow> rows = Data_Table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("postcode").ToList();

Comment: David, please see the update (order by did not sort the numbers)

Comment: This is more complicated than just sorting by the number parts of the address. Some addresses will have names `"101A"` and `"101B"` and those addresses may be split into separate apartments or PO Boxes. Addresses on streets may run even up one-side, odds the other. The numbers may run up one-side, then down the other side. These are only conventions not rules. Some properties will not have numbers, just names. In some cases properties (in close proximity) will have the same name but be distinguished by owner surname. These rules will be hard to encode in a where clause.

Comment: See my previous comment, you must define the ordering rules, you cannot assume we know.

Comment: @Sam: Yes it did.  It ordered them as strings.  Because they're strings.  Store your numbers separately from the rest of the string value and store them *as numbers*.  (Though, as another comment already pointed out, not all addresses will have numbers, or at least purely numeric identifiers within a street.  Hell, not all addresses will have streets.)  Address data is non-trivial and full of edge cases.  But if you want to sort numerically then you need *numbers*, not *strings*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
"SELECT * FROM PC where Postcode = '" + postCode + "' Order by  cast(House_number as unsigned)"
```

This will order your data from DB by House numbers.

> Also using Named parameters in the SQL query will be a much better
>   way.

Comment: I already used it. please see the update (order by clause did not sort the numbers)

Comment: No you haven't. You are injecting whatever is in the postCode variable into the middle of your CommandText. If that comes from input somewhere, then you are doing exactly what you are being warned against. Take a look [here](http://www.bobby-tables.com/csharp) for how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably just means adding 'order by house_number' to the SELECT statement.

Also **do not** build your SQL Select statement by concatenating strings. Using named parameters is the correct way to do this, otherwise you are leaving yourself open to injection attacks.

Comment: I already used it. please see the update (order by clause did not sort the numbers)